# Data dependency of linked clones in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, clone

What is the data dependency between parent and child clone? I know that e.g. installations in the child clone are not available in the parent (that's the reason to have children). But are changes in the parent after the clone available in every child?

I want to have 3 different guest OS as parent VMs and each parent got around >5 child VMs with different versions of the software I need to test. I don't want to maintain every single VM with OS-Updates, so I am wondering if it would work to just update the parent VM and all the child VMs are also updated?

I have read the documentation of linked clones in VirtualBox ([oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/user/clone.html), [How to differ linked clone from a full clone in VirtualBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31405537/how-to-differ-linked-clone-from-a-full-clone-in-virtualbox)), but haven't found any information about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am wondering if it would work to just update the parent VM and all
> the child VMs are also updated?

No.  Virtual machines are independent of each other.

So you need to update each one.

What you can do in VMware is create a snapshot and test software in the snapshot and then delete or combine the snapshot. That is not really what you are looking for but that is a capability of VNmware.

Also Windows 10 and 11 can distribute updates to other machines.  But that is a Windows feature and updates still have to be run.

Comment: Is there any chance to avoid that? I guess VMWare or others have the same "problem"?

Comment: I use VMware myself and each machine must be updated .  That is how VMs work

Comment: Okay, thank you.